# Проблема с короткой записью условийй PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<select name="relationship">
        <?php echo '<option value="Не выбрано"' . ($user->relationship == '') ? ' selected>Не выбрано</option>' : '>Не выбрано</option>'; ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="Не женат"' . ($user->relationship == 'Не женат') ? ' selected>Не женат</option>' : '>Не женат</option>'; ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="Женат"' . ($user->relationship == 'Женат') ? ' selected>Женат</option>' : '>Женат</option>'; ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="Помолвлен"' . ($user->relationship == 'Помолвлен') ? ' selected>Помолвлен</option>' : '>Помолвлен</option>'; ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="В гражданском браке"' . ($user->relationship == 'В гражданском браке') ? ' selected>В гражданском браке</option>' : '>В гражданском браке</option>'; ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="Влюблён"' . ($user->relationship == 'Влюблён') ? ' selected>Влюблён</option>' : '>Влюблён</option>'; ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="Встречаюсь"' . ($user->relationship == 'Встречаюсь') ? ' selected>Встречаюсь</option>' : '>Встречаюсь</option>'; ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="Всё сложно"' . ($user->relationship == 'Всё сложно') ? ' selected>Всё сложно</option>' : '>Всё сложно</option>'; ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="В активном поиске"' . ($user->relationship == 'В активном поиске') ? ' selected>В активном поиске</option>' : '>В активном поиске</option>'; ?>
    </select>
```

После отработки этого кода он выдаёт:

```
 <select name="relationship">
         selected>Не выбрано</option>             selected>Не женат</option>             selected>Женат</option>             selected>Помолвлен</option>             selected>В гражданском браке</option>             selected>Влюблён</option>             selected>Встречаюсь</option>             selected>Всё сложно</option>             selected>В активном поиске</option>        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

всё PHP-выражение, результат которого должен быть конкатенирован, надо взять в скобки